# Going back by one day with date in string format

Tags: python, do-loops

I am trying to execute a code iteratively rather than manually.
What I would like to do is as follows: I add as an input a date (string format)

```
start=input("Start: mm/dd/yyyy ")
```

and I set this date equal to the end date:

```
end=start
```

then I run some code

```
func1(start, end)
```

So my actually code is the following:

```
start=input("\nStart: mm/dd/yyyy ")
end=start
func1(start, end)
```

when `func1` finishes to run, the code stop. So I would need to manually add a new date again and execute the code.
I would like to do, however, the following:

- to set an end date which stops the loop when start is equal to this date;
- considers going back through time by one day a time.

So, for example: if my start date is `06/26/2020` (input string format), my end date would be `06/26/2020` and my code runs. When it finishes to run, I should go back to start date `06/25/2020` (input string format at the moment), i.e. one day before my original start date, and end date `06/25/2020` and let the code run again.

So I would have

```
(1)
start = 06/26/2020
end = 06/26/2020
func1(start, end)

(2)
start = 06/25/2020
end = 06/25/2020
func1(start, end)

(3)
start = 06/24/2020
end = 06/24/2020
func1(start, end)
```

and so on.
This is a loop that it should run until the date (`start`) reaches `06/01/2020`.

The problem is that the date is in the string format and I do not know how to go back by one in order to iterate the code via a `do`-loop.

Update:

If one tries the following:

```
start ="06/26/2020"
day = datetime.strptime(start,'%m/%d/%Y')
for i in range(5):
    
    start=str(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    end=start

    print (day - timedelta(days=i))
```

it does not go back by one day but it prints the same date.

Comment: Check out the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module...

Comment: Thanks MattDMo. I was looking at the same, but it is not clear how to apply it to keep the string format of date

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string format time and convert it to datetime format in python, then you can freely compare two datetime variables and terminate your loop.

```
from datetime import datetime
time_str = '06/26/2020'
# t is datetime type
t = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%m/%d/%Y')

# output: False
print(t < datetime.now())
```

### EDIT2:

About your UPDATE, it should print like that:

```
2020-06-26 00:00:00
2020-06-25 00:00:00
2020-06-24 00:00:00
2020-06-23 00:00:00
2020-06-22 00:00:00
```

But it won't change values of `start` and `end` variables. So I suggest to do it like this:

```
start ="06/26/2020"
day = datetime.strptime(start,'%m/%d/%Y')
for i in range(5):
    start=str(day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    end=start
    print('start:', start)
    print('end:', end)
    # move day 
    day = day - timedelta(days=1)
```

Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Rui. What is text? should it be `time_str`? Another thing: how can I go back by one day, i.e. `06/26/2020`, then `06/25/2020`, then `06/24/2020` and so on until a input date `06/01/2020`?

Comment: Yes, it is time_str. Sorry for that. Timus' answer showed how to go back by one day.

Comment: Thanks Rui. Appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

Just as an illustration (in addition to Rui's post), not as a complete answer:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day_str = '06/26/2020'
day = datetime.strptime(day_str,'%m/%d/%Y')
for i in range(5):
    print(day - timedelta(days=i))
```

**EDIT**: If you need the string-format inside the loop then you could try:

```
day_str = '06/26/2020'
day = datetime.strptime(day_str,'%m/%d/%Y')
for i in range(5):
    print((day - timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

**EDIT2**: Not sure if I understand correctly but look at:

```
str_start ="06/26/2020"
print(str_start)
day_start = datetime.strptime(start,'%m/%d/%Y')
day_end = day_start - timedelta(days=1)
str_end = day_end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(str_end)
```

Comment: Hi Timus thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the problem is in the format. I would need a string format and of the type I shown `(mm/dd/yyyy)` while   `print(day - timedelta(days=i))` gives me a different format and type. So what I would need is actually a change in format inside the `for` cycle which allows me to redefine the start date and set the end date equals to the start one in a string format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: Hm, the string output from `(day - timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` is actually in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: I updated the question to show where the problem is. Thanks in the meantime for your update ;)

Comment: Did you use `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`? This error hints that you somewhere didn't assign the right values to a variable.